# Strange error when running my project

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, xcode4.3

When trying to run my project I get this error and I don´t know what it means :

> _OBJC_CLASS_$_MyWindowController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What does it mean and how can I get rid of it?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the application target, go to the **Build Phases** tab and make sure **MyWindowController.m** is in **Compile Sources**, otherwise add it.

Also, if you use a **xib** file associated with it, make sure it is in **Copy Bundle Resources**.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the framework that your MyWindowController object is based on has been added to your project.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this hint, but it didn´t apply in this case. The previous hint did the trick. I will remember when getting this again :)