# compiler error preventing iOS project from compiling

Tags: objective-c, ios, flickr, cs193p

I'm doing assignment 4 of cs193p from itunes u (fall 2011 Stanford iOS development course)

The assignment is to create a flickr app - they provide a flick helper class called flickrfetcher.

I've copied in the flickrfetcher .h & .m files (available http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/assignments/FlickrFetcher.zip), included the .h file in my viewcontroller.

the project compiles fine, until I make a call to the flickrfetcher class, at which point I get 2 errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlickrFetcher", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in flickrthingViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Now after doing some searching, I've found occasional mentions of similar things, with the only real suggestion that makes sense being that I need to add the coredata framework. Which I've done. It still doesn't work.

There is nothing wrong with my system, as if I download the sample project demonstrated on the course, which uses the same library, it compiles and runs fun. (which incidentally doesn't include coredata

I even tried copying those files from that project to mine, just in case there was some minor difference. Still not working.

I'm hoping (and assuming) that it's some silly minor thing.

I'm running the latest version of xcode, and fairly clueless as to what to try next!

Comment: I'd bet you're using a pre-built static library for iOS, and of course it won't go with the Mac's i386 processor since it's for ARM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange error when running my project](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9441387/1207152)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the `FlickrFetcher.m` file in the project navigator. Now in the right bar, under "Target Membership" tick the box next to the name of your app.

Comment: so simple yet so frustrating until you know what to do! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Select your target and look at the build phases tab.  Open the compile sources section and check whether FlickrFetcher.m is there.  If not, add it.